# Rotating arbitrary plane to be z-axis-aligned

Tags: matrix, 3d, rotation

Correct me if I'm wrong, but...

Given the normal of an arbitrary source plane, and the normal of the plane after applying a desired rotation:

```
Vector3F sourceNormal = (x, y, z).normalize()
Vector3F desiredNormal = (0, 0, 1).normalize()
```

1) We can find the "axis of rotation" through the cross-product of the two normals

```
Vector3F rotationAxis = Vector3F.cross(sourceNormal, desiredNormal).normalize()
```

2) We can find the "angle of rotation" through the arc-cosine of the dot product of the two normals.

```
// Thanks nico - it was there in my project source, but it was omitted here.
float theta = Math.acos(Vector3F.dot(sourceNormal, desiredNormal))
```

3) We can apply the rotation to a set of points in order to orient the source plane to our desired plane.

```
float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];

// X component
rotationMatrix[5] = rotationMatrix[10] = (float)Math.cos(theta);
rotationMatrix[9] = (float)Math.sin(theta);
rotationMatrix[6] = -rotationMatrix[9];

// Y component
rotationMatrix[0] = rotationMatrix[10] = (float)Math.cos(theta);
rotationMatrix[2] = (float)Math.sin(theta);
rotationMatrix[8] = -rotationMatrix[2];

// Z component
rotationMatrix[0] = rotationMatrix[5] = (float)Math.cos(theta);
rotationMatrix[1] = (float)Math.sin(theta);
rotationMatrix[4] = -rotationMatrix[1];

for(Point3F point : polygon)
{
    float x = pt.getX();
    float y = pt.getY();
    float z = pt.getZ();
    float[] xs = new float[3];
    float[] ys = new float[3];
    float[] zs = new float[3];
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
    xs[j] = rotationMatrix[j] * x;
    ys[j] = rotationMatrix[j + 4] * y;
    zs[j] = rotationMatrix[j + 8] * z;
    }
    x = 0; y = 0; z = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
    x += xs[j];
    y += ys[j];
    z += zs[j];
    }
    pt.set(x, y, z);
}
```

My output is incorrect.

In Points:

```
(-56.00, 72.01, 48.02)
(-48.00, 72.01, 48.02)
(-48.00, 86.01, 24.02)
(-56.00, 86.01, 24.02)
```

Out Points:

```
(-124.960010, -88.105451, 24.185812)
(-107.108590, -88.105451, 24.185812)
(-107.108590, -105.237051, 12.0929052)
(-124.960010, -105.237051, 12.0929052)
```

If I had to guess, I'd say that I am applying the rotations to the points incorrectly...perhaps I've interpreted the rotation matrix found in this article ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix ) incorrectly?

Thanks for any input.

...assuming that this is the correct way to set up the rotation matrix, the output is still incorrect:

```
Vector3F axis = Vector3F.cross(sourceNormal, desiredNormal).normalize();
float angle = (float) Math.acos(p.normal.dot(new Vector3F(0, 0, 1)));
float s = (float)Math.sin(angle);
float c = (float)Math.cos(angle);
float x = axis.getX(), y = axis.getY(), z = axis.getZ();
float[] matrix = new float[16];
matrix[0] = x * x * (1 - c) + c;
matrix[1] = x * y * (1 - c) - (z * s);
matrix[2] = x * z * (1 - c) + (y * s);

matrix[4] = y * x * (1 - c) + (z * s);
matrix[5] = y * y * (1 - c) + c;
matrix[6] = y * z * (1 - c) - (x * s);

matrix[8] = x * z * (1 - c) - (y * s);
matrix[9] = y * z * (1 - c) + (x * s);
matrix[10] = z * z * (1 - c) + c;


float nx = x * matrix[0] + y * matrix[1] + z * matrix[2];
float ny = x * matrix[4] + y * matrix[5] + z * matrix[6];
float nz = x * matrix[8] + y * matrix[9] + z * matrix[10];

In: (-56.00, 56.01, -16.02)
In: (-48.00, 56.01, -16.02)
In: (-48.00, 72.01, -8.02)
In: (-56.00, 72.01, -8.02)
Out: (-51.270340, 46.887921, -25.5108342)
Out: (-43.9460070, 46.887921, -25.5108342)
Out: (-43.9460070, 62.798761, -21.5554182)
Out: (-51.270340, 62.798761, -21.5554182)
```

Comment: 1) is wrong. Didn't you test it?

Comment: By "test it", the only conclusive evidence that I've gathered is that the ultimate output is incorrect.  Thank you for pointing out (at least) one flaw in the process.  I'll look into it.  However, If I'm going about this completely wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Also, could you please elaborate on how exactly one is to test step 1?  My mind does not function very well in more than 2 dimensions in terms of visualization.

Comment: @Beta: Why is 1) wrong? The only problem I can see is that the `acos` is missing in the calculation of `theta`.

Comment: Furthermore, make sure that the `a = b = c` syntax leads to the results you expect. Not all programming languages interpret this the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the points, Nico.  I've updated the question to include that in my original source, the arc-cosine is used.  I can confirm that the a = b = c syntax is correct, as my camera class uses the same matrix implementation internally and functions correctly.

Comment: Your rotation matrix looks too simple - see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RodriguesRotationFormula.html and also http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/glRotatef/

Comment: I swear, once I nail this down I'm going to post an algorithm for this so that no one else will waste days trying to debug something so simple.

Comment: @LukeA.Leber the correct matrix is right there in the Wikipedia article too

Comment: @NicoSchertler: 1) is wrong because when you rotate a plane, the cross product of the two normals (before and after) is not necessarily parallel to the axis of rotation.

Comment: To test 1), you might take a plane, pick a rotation axis and angle of rotation at random, perform the rotation, take the cross-product of the normals, normalize it and see if you get the rotation axis you picked.

Comment: @Beta: Of course you can rotate a plane around an axis that does not lie in the plane. But this is usually not the shortest rotation. The cross product as stated in 1) is correct because it calculates the shortest rotation around an in-plane axis. There may be other rotations that achieve the same result. Not mentioning degenerate cases...

Comment: @NicoSchertler: you're assuming things that aren't in the question, but what you're saying may well be what the OP has in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rotation matrix is wrong.

The rotations need to be combined per the formula in Section 10 of the Wikipedia article you've linked to ("*Rotation matrix from axis and angle*").

A simplified version of this matrix can also be found in the manual page for the [`glRotate`](http://manpagez.com/man/3/glRotatef) function.

NB: unless you're repeating the rotation over and over, there's no need to take `acos(dotp)` only to take the `cos` and `sin` of it again.  Use the dot product directly as `cos(theta)`, and use the relationship `sin(theta)^2 = 1 - cos(theta)^2` to work out `sin(theta)`.

Comment: I've updated the question with a *supposedly* correct rotation matrix.  The output is still incorrect, however...so either I've gotten the matrix wrong again, or there's another problem.  Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I should also mention that this is not performance critical code.  It is simply used in a conversion tool used to triangulate some 3D models (hopefully as a one-time operation before packaging into the application).  All it has to do is *work*.

Comment: @LukeA.Leber I can't see any obvious errors (although it would simplify the code if you factored out the repeated calls to `axis.getX()` etc).  The answers do at least appear plausible now (the vector lengths appear consistent).

Comment: @LukeA.Leber it _might_ be your matrix multiplication code, which on first examination looks a little _odd_...

Comment: Sorry, I am getting quite frustrated with this after spending over 12 hours on it.  I'll refactor the above code.  Thanks for your continued support.  And it probably doesn't help that my last linear algebra class was over 10 years ago.

Comment: @LukeA.Leber I suggest you write out the matrix multiplication by hand (e.g. `float nx = x * m[0] + y * m[1] + z * m[2]`) - it should only take three such lines of code.

Comment: I've updated the question once again following your advice...however the output is still incorrect.  At this point, would it be safe to assume that there is an error in either the cross product, dot product, or normalization?

Comment: Your code doesn't reflect the (edited) expression in my above comment.  (I'm breaking for lunch now  BTW)

Comment: I've updated the code yet again.  Taking a break does sound like a good idea at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, there were many issues.  Alnitak solved the vast majority of them, and I've just found the last one.

In short, the following were wrong:

1) Matrix Creation

2) Matrix Multiplication

3) Floating Point Truncation

Even if it might be a hacky solution, it's fine for my purposes.  The working snip is below.

```
Vector3F axis = new Vector3F(p.normal);
// Seems to work when adding precision...but NOT with (0, 0, 1)
Vector3F target = new Vector3F(0.000000000000000001f, 0.000000000000001f, 1.0f);
axis.cross(target);
axis.normalize();
float angle = (float) Math.acos(p.normal.dot(new Vector3F(0, 0, 1)));
float s = (float) Math.sin(angle);
float c = (float) Math.cos(angle);
float x = axis.getX(), y = axis.getY(), z = axis.getZ();
float[] matrix = new float[16];
matrix[0] = x * x * (1 - c) + c;
matrix[1] = x * y * (1 - c) - (z * s);
matrix[2] = x * z * (1 - c) + (y * s);
matrix[4] = y * x * (1 - c) + (z * s);
matrix[5] = y * y * (1 - c) + c;
matrix[6] = y * z * (1 - c) - (x * s);
matrix[8] = x * z * (1 - c) - (y * s);
matrix[9] = y * z * (1 - c) + (x * s);
matrix[10] = z * z * (1 - c) + c;

float nx = x * matrix[0] + y * matrix[1] + z * matrix[2];
float ny = x * matrix[4] + y * matrix[5] + z * matrix[6];
float nz = x * matrix[8] + y * matrix[9] + z * matrix[10];

// triangulate (now 2D) polygon
// Rotate the points back
angle = -angle;
s = (float) Math.sin(angle);
c = (float) Math.cos(angle);
matrix[0] = x * x * (1 - c) + c;
matrix[1] = x * y * (1 - c) - (z * s);
matrix[2] = x * z * (1 - c) + (y * s);
matrix[4] = y * x * (1 - c) + (z * s);
matrix[5] = y * y * (1 - c) + c;
matrix[6] = y * z * (1 - c) - (x * s);
matrix[8] = x * z * (1 - c) - (y * s);
matrix[9] = y * z * (1 - c) + (x * s);
matrix[10] = z * z * (1 - c) + c;
nx = x * matrix[0] + y * matrix[1] + z * matrix[2];
ny = x * matrix[4] + y * matrix[5] + z * matrix[6];
nz = x * matrix[8] + y * matrix[9] + z * matrix[10];
// All's well that ends well
```

Comment: I suggest you try my hint about not doing `acos` followed by `cos` to see if it fixes your precision problem.